# Create dict from values from two other dicts

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a program that is running two different API's.  From the first API
I create a dict that is `{SERIAL_NO: NAME}`

From the second API I create another dict that is `{SERIAL_NO: <integer value>}`

I can't get `NAME` and the corresponding `<integer value>` from a single API call.

The length of both dicts is the same, and the `SERIAL_NO`'s are the same in both dicts.

I want a new dict that is:  `{NAME: <integer value>}`

The values from the first dict are the keys and the values from the second dict are the values in the new dict.

The `NAME: <integer value>` pair must both be from the same `SERIAL_NO` in the original dicts.

```
new_dict = {}
for key in dict1:
    if key in dict2:
        ???
```

I'm not sure how to create the new dict using the values from the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're so close! You just need to look up the values!

```
new_dict = {}
for key in dict1:
    if key in dict2:
        new_dict[dict1[key]] = dict2[key]
```